# Store hash with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash

I am using Node.js to generate a hash for a file and then when it is changed, I want to match it with the previous version before saving it. For example, if no change has happened, no save will be done.

I try the following code to do the task (inspired by [doc of Node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm)):

```
var filename = __dirname + '/public/team.html';
var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');

var s = fs.ReadStream(filename);
s.on('data', function(d) {
  shasum.update(d);
});

s.on('end', function() {
  var d = shasum.digest('hex');
  console.log(d + '  ' + filename);
});
```

I was wondering how I can save the hash of the file in order to match it afterwards. Any ideas would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: just write it to a file (one additional info file per file you are saving).

A bit more complex solution: keep one file with all hashes like pairs (path, hash). You have to load the file, parse the data and save it afterwards each time.

Proper solution: use database. It should be very easy with SQLite and you won't need a separate database server. Here's an example of a driver for NodeJS:

https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3

Comment: OK then I go with the proper solution but I'm not familiar with SQLite. Is it something similar to MongoDB?

Comment: If you already are familiar with MongoDB, then do it with MongoDB (assuming you don't mind setting up database server). SQLite is similar to MongoDB only in the sense that they are both databases. :D SQLite is an SQL database and as such is quite similar to MySQL or any other SQL database. The only major difference is that SQLite does not require separate server (which actually is not necessary an advantage, depends on your needs).