# Crypto module - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-crypto

Which is the simplest way to compare a hash of a file without storing it in a database?

For example:

```
var filename = __dirname + '/../public/index.html';
var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');

var s = fs.ReadStream(filename);
s.on('data', function(d) {
  shasum.update(d);
});

s.on('end', function() {
  var d = shasum.digest('hex');
  console.log(d + ' ' + filename);

  fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/../public/log.txt", d.toString() + '\n', function(err) {
     if(err) {
         console.log(err);
      } else {
         console.log("The file was saved!");
      }
  }); 
});
```

The above code returns the hash of the HTML file. If I edit the file how can I know if it has been changed? In other words, how can I know if the hash has been changed?

Any suggestions?

**Edited**

Now the hash is being saved in the log file. How can I retrieve the hash from the file and match it with the new generated one? A code example would be awesome to give me a better understanding.

There is no difference with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789744/store-hash-with-node-js), but it isn't clear for me yet how to implement it.

Comment: What's the format of the log file? And what is the nature of the log file(s)? Is there one 'log file' per html file? Or what?

Comment: OK let's say the format is .txt. At the moment, there is one log.txt and each time I modify the HTML file, a new hash overwrites the previous one in the file. Is a way to match the new hash with the previous one before overwriting it? Is there a much simpler way for doing the same thing?

Comment: See if the new answer, or the edit to my answer, helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for changes on a file, then you can use one of Node's filesystem functions, `fs.watch`. This is how it's used:

```
fs.watch(filename, function (event, filename) {
  //event is either 'rename' or 'change'
  //filename is the name of the file which triggered the event
});
```

The watch function is however not very consistent, so you can use `fs.watchFile` as an alternative. `fs.watchFile` uses stat polling, so it's quite a bit slower than `fs.watch`, which detects file changes instantly.

Watching a file will return an instance of `fs.FSWatcher`, which has the events `change` and `error`. Calling `.close` will stop watching for changes on the file.

Here's an example relating to your code:

```
var filename = __dirname + '/../public/index.html';
var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');

var oldhash = null;

var s = fs.ReadStream(filename);
s.on('data', function(d) {
  shasum.update(d);
});

s.on('end', function() {
  var d = shasum.digest('hex');
  console.log(d + ' ' + filename);
  oldhash = d.toString();

  fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/../public/log.txt", d.toString() + '\n', function(err) {
     if(err) {
         console.log(err);
      }
      else {
         console.log("The file was saved!");
      }
  }); 
});

//watch the log for changes
fs.watch(__dirname + "/../public/log.txt", function (event, filename) {
  //read the log contents
  fs.readFile(__dirname + "/../public/log.txt", function (err, data) {
    //match variable data with the old hash
    if (data == oldhash) {
      //do something
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference between this question and the [previous one you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789744/store-hash-with-node-js)? If you're not wanting to store it in a database, then store it as a file. If you want to save the hash for multiple files, then maybe put them in a JSON object and write them out as a .json file so they're easy to read/write.

**EDIT**

Given what you added to your question, it should be pretty simple. You might write a function to do check and re-write:

```
function updateHash (name, html, callback) {
    var sha = crypto.createHash('sha1');
    sha.update(html);
    var newHash = sha.digest('hex');

    var hashFileName = name + '.sha';

    fs.readFile(hashFileName, 'utf8', function (err, oldHash) {
        var changed = true;
        if (err)
            console.log(err); // probably indicates the file doesn't exist, but you should consider doing better error handling

        if (oldHash === newHash)
            changed = false;

        fs.writeFile(hashFileName, newHash, { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err) {
            callback(err, changed);
        });
    });
}

updateHash('index.html', "<html><head><title>...", function (err, isChanged) {
    // do something with this information ?
    console.log(isChanged);
});
```